# How to correctly scroll a page to download each one of available zip files using Selenium on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, debugging, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar

I'm trying to download all of the zip files from [this page](https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/futures/um/daily/markPriceKlines/ALICEUSDT/1h/) that don't end with the word **'CHECKSUM'**, so far I have managed to write a code that it's supposed to do that but it's not working as expected, here it is:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222") #this allows bulk-dozer to take control of your Chrome Browser in DevTools mode.
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions

#Why using MarkPrices: https://support.btse.com/en/support/solutions/articles/43000557589-index-price-and-mark-price#:~:text=Index%20Price%20is%20an%20important,of%20cryptocurrencies%20on%20major%20exchanges.&text=Mark%20Price%20is%20the%20price,be%20fair%20and%20manipulation%20resistant.
time.sleep(2)
if driver.current_url == 'https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/futures/um/daily/markPriceKlines/ALICEUSDT/1h/' :   
    number = 2 #initialize an int variable to 2 because the desired web elements in this page starts from 2
    counter = 0
    while number <= np.size(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="listing"]/tr')): #iterate over the tbody array
        data_file_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="listing"]/tr[{number}]/td[1]/a').text
        if data_file_name.endswith('CHECKSUM') == False:
            current_data_file = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="listing"]/tr[{number}]/td[1]/a')
            element_position = current_data_file.location
            y_position = str(element_position.get('y'))
            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollBy(0,{y_position})", "") #scroll down the page to know what's being added
            current_data_file.click()
            print(f'saving {data_file_name}')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            counter += 1            
        number += 1
    print(counter)
```

My problem occurs at the 20th element (`ALICEUSDT-1h-2022-02-04.zip.CHECKSUM`), the program stops and throws errors like the one down below:

> **ElementClickInterceptedException:** element click intercepted: Element
> is not clickable at point (418, 1294)

Or this other one with a negative position:

> **ElementClickInterceptedException:** element click intercepted: Element
> is not clickable at point (418, -1221)

So, I would like to know how could I improve the code above to handle the errors shown, I know it has everything to do with the scrollbar, but I ran out of ideas after using this other line `y_position = str(element_position.get('y')+100)` and keep getting the same errors.

Comment: It could be an overlapping element.

Comment: The only overlapping element that could exist is the Downloads bar at the bottom of the browser, however it have no idea how to close it every time it appears after clicking an element, do you happen to know? @ArundeepChohan